# Shell command - condition based on output of command?

Tags: shell, conditional-statements

I'm trying to run some shell command if a string is not present in a text file. If I paste this line into the command line if gives me an error.

```
if [ $(cat textfile.txt | grep "search string") -eq "" ]; then; echo "some string"; fi;
```

Error:

```
-bash: [: -eq: unary operator expected
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use `[]` for comparison you need to use `=` instead of `-eq`. You also need some quotes.

```
if [ "$(cat textfile.txt | grep 'search string')" = "" ]; then; echo "some string"; fi;
```

Note that `grep` can take a filename as argument so the `cat` is unnecessary. You can also directly use the return value of `grep`: grep returns 1 if the search string is not found.

```
if [ "$(grep 'search string' textfile.txt)" ]; then
  echo "some string";
fi
```

An even more compact way would be to use logical and `&&`.

```
grep "search string" textfile.txt && echo "some string"
```

Comment: You don't have to change the quotes, this is perfectly valid bash: `"$(cat textfile.txt | grep "search string")"`

Answer (score 2):

The `grep` command will return 0 if the requested lines are found (1 if not, 2 if an error), so you can just use:

```
grep "search string" textfile.txt >/dev/null 2>&1
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]] ; then
    echo 'Not found'
fi
```

If you *really* wanted to use strings (and you probably shouldn't), you should quote them so that you don't get too many arguments for the `[` command:

```
if [ "$(cat textfile.txt | grep 'search string')" == "" ] ; then
    echo "It's not there!"
fi
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but your answer is far from optimal: There is no need to do redirections because `grep` has a `-q` option, and Bash can test for the return value of a command without resorting to `$?`.

Comment: That's okay, Philipp. Not all greps have those options (I still work with a few legacy UNIXes) and I wouldn't be shell scripting for efficiency anyway. I'll be incorporating your answer into my (modern) scripts in future so +1 for that.

Answer (score 2):

```
grep -F -q -e 'search string' textfile.txt || echo 'Not found'
```

Note:

- `-F` prevents the interpretation of the search string as a regular expression.
- `-q` suppresses all output and returns immediately after the first instance was found, making the search much faster if the string occurs at the beginning of a large file.
- `-e` specifies the pattern explicitly, allowing patterns that start with a dash.
- Use single quotes unless you want variable substitutions.

Comment: elegance. somewhere along the line, someone tried to turn bash into perl `[[$(` unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

No need for the square brackets in this case. Since `[` is actually a command, any command can be used where you would use it. So here, we can use `grep`. There's no need to use `cat` since `grep` will accept filenames as arguments. Also, you have two too many semicolons.

```
if grep -q "search string" textfile.txt; then echo "some string"; fi
```

or

```
if grep "search string" textfile.txt > /dev/null 2>&1; then echo "some string"; fi
```